# Pivot query is showing wrong results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, survey_product and survey_result table

survey_product looks like this:

```
id product 
1   abc
2   asd
3   xyz
```

survey_result looks like this:

```
id user_id product_id answer
1   2        1          1
2   2        2          0
3   2        3          1
4   3        1          1
5   3        2          0
6   3        3          1
```

I need the result to be:

```
id user abc asd xyz .......
1   2    1   0   1
2   3    1   0   1
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this in MySQL. You have to put case statement and convert them in to columns for all the users available.

```
select s.id,
 case when s.user = 1 then answer else 0 end as 'abc',
 ...
 ...
from survey_result s
join user u on s.user = u.id
group by s.id
```

However you can simply export the result set as csv and do the necessary pivoting in an spreadsheet software like excel.